# Aligning divs to center rather than right side

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-float, margin

I am creating a tiled interface where I will have a responsive tiles based interface.

http://metroui.org.ua/tiles.html

One issues that I found to be facing is all tiles always tend to shift to left hand side of the div and does not get center aligned whatever may I try.

check right border here -
[image: Right side there is always some space]

I tried multiple things with positioning and margins, but I am not able to reach any conclusions. for how to make all tiles centrally aligned rather than left side.

Can any one guide me with same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Kaushik

Not 100% sure what you want aligned but I would use flex box.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
  <li class="flex-item">6</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  line-height: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

You can also plat around with replacing `justify-content: center;` above with:

```
 justify-content: space-around;
```

OR

```
 justify-content: space-between;
```